# Android ffmpeg white space in input path causing "no such file or directory"

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using the latest version of [WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library.

I've tried single/double quoting the path with no success.

I Logged my command after execution,
please look to the input path where a subDirectory contains whiteSpace, a comma  has been added between the space:

```
ffmpeg, -i, "storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram, Video/4_5828137322067002802.mp4", -vf...
```

I split and run my command like this:

```
String crop = "-ss " + skipTimeForCrop + " -noautorotate -i " + newPath + " -vframes 10 -vf cropdetect=24:16:0 -f null -";
String[] cropCommand = crop.trim().split(" ");
execFFmpegForCrop(cropCommand);
```

> storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram: No such file or directory

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe adding commands as `List` and then converting it to array will solve this problem,

This way the commas should only add to the end of every single commands. I'll show you how:

```
List<String> commandList = new LinkedList<>();
commandList.add("-ss");
commandList.add("00:00:00");
commandList.add("-noautorotate");
commandList.add("-i");
commandList.add("storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram Video/4_5828137322067002802.mp4");
commandList.add("-vframes");
commandList.add("10");
commandList.add("-vf");
commandList.add("-cropdetect=24:16:0");
.
.
.

 String[] cropCommand  = commandList.toArray(new String[commandList.size()]);
 execFFmpegForCrop(cropCommand);
```

And this will be the output:

```
"[-ss, 00:00:00, -noautorotate, -i, storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram Video/4_5828137322067002802.mp4, -vframes, 10, -vf, -cropdetect=24:16:0, ...]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use command `String[] cropCommand = crop.trim().split(" ");`
This will cut the file name contains whitespace " " and the input file will be fail

Answer (score 0):

try to use double backslashes before the space:

`"storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram,\\ Video/4_5828137322067002802.mp4"`

Answer (score 0):

first replace whitespace of filepath with some creepy string, then while running ffmpeg.execute() replace that creepy string with space.

like:

```
String input_path = txt_selected_file.getText().toString().replace(" ","%20");

String cmd = "-i "+ input_path+" -vn -ab 320 -preset ultrafast /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Messenger/test.mp3";
                executeCmd(cmd);

in executecmd() method

private void executeCmd(final String command) {

        try {
            String[] cmd = command.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i<cmd.length;i++){
                cmd[i] = cmd[i].replace("%20"," ");
            }

}
```