# ffmpeg not working with filename have whitespace

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, whitespace

My file name is a folder with image series (image_0001.png,image_0002.png...)

```
 /storage/emulated/0/My Image/image_%04d.png
```

I tried with quote ""

```
-i "/storage/emulated/0/My Image/image_%04d.png"
```

and %20

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/My%20Image/image_%04d.png
```

But it not working. How can i do this ?

My command

```
 -f image2 -i /storage/emulated/0/background.png -i /data/user/0/My Image/image_%04d.png -filter_complex [1:v]scale=200.0:200.0[scale];[0:v][scale]overlay=0.0:0.0 /storage/emulated/0/output.mp4
```

Error

```
: /data/user/0/My: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How do you execute this command on your android phone? Through java code? adb shell? a terminal emulator?

Comment: @oguzismail i use lib FFmpegAndroid-0.3.2

Comment: I found my issue solution in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573542/android-ffmpeg-white-space-in-input-path-causing-no-such-file-or-directory/53405279#53405279)

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg has special rules for quoting and escaping. Found [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) on their website.

So using quotes (' ') should work for you.

Comment: I tried but it not working . ffmpeg still get whitespace

/storage/emulated/0/My\: No such file or directory

Comment: can you please edit your question and add the piece of code you are using?

Comment: thanks. worked for me when using the "flutter_ffmpeg" plugin in flutter :)

Comment: wrapping the entire file path with a single quote worked for me